# Can keep alive be enabled over secure https?

Tags: .htaccess, keep-alive

I've been trying to enable Keep Alive on my `https` site with no luck. Is it possible? Sometimes I see on my test page it says "connection closed."

Here's what I have in my `htaccess` right now that doesn't seem to work:

```
Header set Connection keep-alive
KeepAlive On
MaxKeepAliveRequests 100
KeepAliveTimeout 15 
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "doesn't seem to work" - If you had that in an .htaccess file I would have expected to see a 500 Internal Server Error (in which case, check your server's error log), if it did anything at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The KeepAlive directive is perfectly valid for HTTPS; in fact it is most advantageous with HTTPS. On the other hand, the valid context of the [KeepAlive directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#keepalive) is "server config, virtual host." [This means](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) that you cannot do this in an `.htaccess` file.